# How to calculate $\int_A |1-y| dx dy $ on a set A

Tags: real-analysis

I have a set $A=\{(x,y) \in R^2 : 0 \le x \le 2-y,(x-1)^2+y^2 \ge 1\}$.

I want to calculate $\int_A |1-y| dx dy$.

I have to study te absolute value?

Answer (score 1):

Your area is as follows:

[image]

$$A=D_1+D_2$$

Now in $D_1$ we have $$\theta|_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2},~~r|_{2\cos(\theta)}^{\csc(\theta)}$$ and on $D_2$ we have :$$\theta|_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2},~~r|_{\csc(\theta)}^{\frac{2}{\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)}}$$

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{\sqrt(1-(x-1)^2)}^{1} (1-y) dy$+$\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{1}^{2-x} (y-1) dy$?

Comment: In cartesian coordinates, your integral is $\int_{y=0}^{1}\int_{x=0}^{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}(y-1)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y=1}^2\int_{x=0}^{2-y}(1-y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$.

Comment: why is (y-1) in the first integral?

Comment: The Nicolas's is simpler than mine. in fact in D1 the absolute value is positive because $y<1$.